# cache smb mount on local hard drive

Tags: linux, cache, smb

I have a smb mount on my linux server, but occasionally it loses connection, interrupting the software using the mounted directory. Is there a way to cache the smb mount on local disk?

Comment: What do you mean by "cache the smb mount"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a SMB share mounted when in use. I would recommend using `autofs` for this.

Install autofs if not currently available and cifs-utils.

```
sudo apt-get install autofs cifs-utils # Or
sudo yum install autofs cifs-utils
```

Enable the service at boot.

```
sudo systemctl enable autofs
sudo systemctl start autofs
```

Setup config files.

**/etc/auto.master**

```
/path/to/mountpoint /etc/auto.<my_server>
```

**/etc/auto.<my_server>**

```
<any_name> -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/path/to/creds.txt ://<remove_server>/<share_name>
```

**/path/to/creds.txt** *make sure to do chmod 600 on file*

```
username=Username
password=Password
```

Reload the service `sudo systemctl restart autofs`

**Some links for more information**

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_file_systems/assembly_mounting-file-systems-on-demand_managing-file-systems#doc-wrapper

You can also do this with `fstab` but the key difference here is when the smb share is not in use `autofs` will timeout the mount and free resources, while `fstab` will keep it mounted and use resources. You can set no timeout for autofs if it is important with `--timeout=0` but I would recommend against it to save resources.

If you want to avoid autofs you can follow the below method for fstab. You will still need to create a creds file.

**Add to /etc/fstab**

```
//<server>/<share> /path/to/mount cifs credentials=/path/to/creds.txt 0 0
```